# Pop(char &) fcn from stack of char's

Tags: c++, stack

I am trying to implement a basic char stack to increase my understanding of stacks. Im confused as to why I am able to push correctly onto the stack, but I cannot pop form the stack, I get a seg fault.

This is my header file

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Stack {
    public:
            Stack(int = 10);
            Stack(const Stack&);
            ~Stack();
            Stack& operator=(const Stack&);
            bool push(char);
            bool pop(char &);
            bool empty() const;
            bool full() const;
            bool clear();
    bool operator==(const Stack&) const;
            //friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const Stack&);
    private:
            int max;
            int top;
            int actual; //only used in stack (stay) implementation
            char* data;
};
```

this is my implementation file with relevant information included only

```
#include <iostream>
#include "stack.h"

using namespace std;

const int MAX = 9;

Stack::Stack(int a) {
    max = a;
    char *data = new char[a];
    int top = 0;
}

Stack::~Stack()
{
    delete[] data;
    data = NULL;
}


bool Stack::push(char c)
{
    if(top==9)
    {
        cout << "stack is full" <<endl;
        return false;
    }
    else
    top++;
    return c;
}

bool Stack::pop(char &c) 
{
    if(top==-1)
    {
        cout << "Stack is empty" << endl;
        return false;
    }
    c = data[top];
    top--;
    return c;

}
```

here is my test file

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include "stack.h"
    //#include "queue.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Stack *stack = new Stack(10);

    char s = 's';
    char t = 't';
    char a = 'a';
    char c = 'c';
    char k = 'k';

    stack->push(s);
    stack->push(t);
    stack->push(a);
    stack->push(c);
    stack->push(k);
    // this is where it seg faults
    stack->pop(s);
    stack->pop(t);
    stack->pop(a);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You initialize `top` to 0, but you test if it is equal to -1 to determine if it is empty. One of those two is not right. As written, you can construct a `Stack` and then immediately call `pop()` (in theory) successfully. Your `push()` also never actually puts the passed value into your array.

Comment: @cdhowie i fixed my initialization, must have been a typo. How do I need to modify push to actually put a value in, and pop to pop a value?

Answer (score 2):

```
char *data = new char[a];
int top = 0;
```

These lines are creating new *local* variables in the constructor.  This means that the `data` field in your class never gets assigned and therefore is an uninitialized pointer; you are attempting to read values from an undefined memory location in `pop()`.

You need to set the data members of the object instead:

```
data = new char[a];
top = -1; // Should actually be -1 according to your test in pop()
```

---

Some other notes:

- In `push()` you never actually store the argument in `data`, so it will never be read back out. `pop()` will return data out of uninitialized memory, so the `char`s you attempt to pop are going to be garbage.
- In the constructor you could use the initializer list instead of assignment:

  ```
  Stack::Stack(int a)
      : max(a),
        top(-1),
        data(new char[a])
  { }
  ```

Comment: thanks for your help, the seg fault is no longer there. So by saying data = new char[a], im moving this froma  local variable to a stack that i can mess around with? 

also, with top = -1, i dont need the int top = 1 beccause ive already said its an int in the .h?

Comment: @matt By saying `data = new char[a]` you are heap-allocating a new `char` array containing `a` elements, and storing a pointer to this array in the `Stack` object's `data` field. `char *data = new char[a]` does the same thing except that it stores the pointer in a variable local to the constructor, a variable that is lost when the constructor returns.

Answer (score 0):

You should make up your mind whether you want `top` to be the index of the top element, or the number of elements on the stack and therefore one past the top. The latter is more common, and fits in with you initializing `top = 0`. But then you want to check for `top == 0` in the `pop` method, and you also want to decrement `top` first and use it to index the element after it has been decremented.